# Cannot resolve error resource xml/data_extraction_rules (aka com.example.pytorch_mobile:xml/data_extraction_rules) not found

Tags: android, xml, pytorch

I am building a android app that runs a pytorch model on emulator. But in my AndroidManifest i am getting the following errors:
resource xml/data_extraction_rules (aka com.example.pytorch_mobile:xml/data_extraction_rules) not found.
resource style/Theme.PyTorch_App (aka com.example.pytorch_mobile:style/Theme.PyTorch_App) not found.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.pytorch_mobile">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PyTorch_App"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <!--        <activity-->
        <!--            android:name=".MainActivity2"-->
        <!--            android:exported="true">-->
        <!--            <intent-filter>-->
        <!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

        <!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        <!--            </intent-filter>-->
        <!--        </activity>-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried cleaning the gradle and doing invalidate cache and restart but it does not work.